# Use Next and Previous Button for Long column chart

Tags: asp.net

is there any way to show alot of columns in asp.net column chart control?
For example, I have 200 cars and I want to show their sum weight in columns, but I want to show only 10 columns in a page, and by clicking Next button show 10 more.

Answer (score 0):

Just look below mentioned tutorial & try to apply it into your code.

http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: Thanks, But I don't use MVC.